# VBA ADODB parameter as dynamic Excel Range

Tags: sql, vba, parameters, adodb

I'm trying to pass a list of parameters to a SQL query in VBA, I have an excel table with a list of codes in a range that is dynamic, could 2, could be 2000. I want to then return all data from SQL where the codes match. Below I'm trying to define an ADODB parameter as an array, then I want to pass that to SQL.

However defining the parameter variable as a range gives a type mismatch. Or Object required if I don't define as an array;

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=XXXXXXXXX; Initial Catalog=CDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Dim code(0) As ADODB.Parameter
Set code(0) = wb.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, colCode), Cells(rowCount, colCode)).Value
'Dim code As ADODB.Parameter
'Set code = wb.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, colCode), Cells(rowCount, colCode)).Value
'Dim code(rowCount - 1) As ADODB.Parameter
'Set code(rowCount - 1) = wb.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, colCode), Cells(rowCount, colCode)).Value
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@code", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10000, code)
    .CommandTimeout = 0
End With

sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE code in (?);"
cmd.CommandText = sql
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: You cannot use a Range (or array) as a parameter, you would need to iterate the range and build a delimited string of (escaped) values & use that in the IN () clause.

Comment: ... or create a parameter for every value in your range (and one `?` in your sql statement)